# exception class EIdHttpProtocolException with message 'HTTP/1,1 500 request is missing the session parameter. Add dss parameter with the session id'"

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, sqlconnection, datasnap

I am learning to write a REST DataSnap application with an window Client.

The DataSnap REST server is behaving correctly. I have added 4 server methods (each selects from the db). All work fine from the Server-side Browser-with-Functions.

Next, the DataSnap Client calls all 4 server methods and displays the results correctly. So, really, the client/server are both working properly, with no exceptions.

However, when I close the Client application, I receive the following exception (twice):

> raised exception class EIdHttpProtocolException with message
>   'HTTP/1,1 500 HTTP request is missing the session parameter. Add dss parameter with the session id'

Here is some info about the client applicaion Datamodule:

1. TSQLCponnection: `SQLConnection1`

   1. Driver: `DataSnap`
   2. KeepConnection: `True`
   3. Params:

      1. DriverUnit: `Data.DBXDataSnap`
      2. Host Name: `192.168.1.3`
      3. Port: `8080`
      4. CommunicationProtocol: `http`
      5. DatasnapContext: `datasnap/filters`
2. TSqlServerMethod: `SqlServerMethod1` (this is one of four)

   1. GetMetadata: `False`
   2. ServerMethodName: `TServerMethods1.GetEmployeesByLastName`
   3. SQLConnection: `SQLConnection1`
3. TSQLDataSet: `SQLDataSet1`

   1. CommandText: `TServerMethods1.GetEmployeesByLastName`
   2. CommandType: `ctServerMethod`
   3. DbxCommandType: `Datasnap.ServerMethod`

      1. Params:

         1. ALastName:
         2. DataType: `ftString`
         3. ParamType: `ptInput`
         4. Size: `10`
         5. ReturnParameter
         6. DataType: `ftDataSet`
         7. ParamType: `ptResult`
   4. SQLConnection: `SQLConnection1`
4. TDataSetProvider: `DataSetProvider1`
5. TClientDataSet: `ClientDataSet1`

Comment: Please have a look at your old question, if there are any acceptable answers

Comment: Thanks for Sir Rufo for your updation. I fixed above issue.